# How to do laravel eager loading with multiple constraints?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eager-loading, eloquent

```
$institutes = Institute::with(['address' => function($query){
                 $query->whereCityId(Input::get('city_id'));
                 $query->whereIn('area_id',Input::get('area_id'));
              }])->get();
```

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: can you elaborate on the error

Comment: I want to get all the institutes with address where city_id which is in addresses table and area_id which is also in addresses table matches the Input conditions

Comment: Please review this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).Here is the More information about the Querying Relations.Use for the whereHas insted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work but it returns

```
address: null
```

wherever the condition matches. But it returns all institutes. Either we can use **filter** on the collection or **whereHas**

```
$institutes = Institute::whereHas('address', function ($query) use ($city_id) {
                   $query->whereCityId($city_id);
              })->get();
```

or

```
$institutes = Institute::with(['address' => function ($query) use ($city_id) {
                   $query->whereCityId($city_id);
              }])->get()->filter(function ($institute){ 
                   return $institute->address != null; 
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be here

```
$query->whereIn('area_id',Input::get('area_id'));
```

Try to ensure that `Input::get('area_id')` actually returns an array:

```
$area = Input::get('area_id') ?: [];
$query->whereIn('area_id',is_string($area) ? json_decode($area, true) : $area);
```

Comment: it does return an array!

Answer (score 0):

is whereCityId the scope of the model? Documentation has examples with scopes chained with models only.

Try replacing the scope with column name and try. ex replaced with `city_id`

```
 $institutes = Institute::with(['address' => function($query){
                     $query->where('city_id',Input::get('city_id'));
                     $query->whereIn('area_id',Input::get('area_id'));
                  }])->get();
```